# How to optimize SELECT query with multiple CASE statements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case, postgresql-9.5

In a two player, [PostgreSQL based game](https://gist.github.com/afarber/c40b9fc5447335db7d24) the most frequently called statement is the SELECT query returning the list of games, which the user is playing:

(Please pardon the non-latin letters in the screenshot)

[image: game screenshot]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION words_get_games(in_uid integer)
        RETURNS TABLE (
                out_gid integer, 
                out_created integer,
                out_finished integer,
                out_letters varchar[15][15],
                out_values integer[15][15],
                out_bid integer,
                out_last_tiles jsonb,
                out_last_score integer,
                out_player1 integer,
                out_player2 integer,
                out_played1 integer,
                out_played2 integer,
                out_hand1 text,
                out_hand2 text,
                out_score1 integer,
                out_score2 integer,
                out_female1 integer,
                out_female2 integer,
                out_given1 varchar,
                out_given2 varchar,
                out_photo1 varchar,
                out_photo2 varchar,
                out_place1 varchar,
                out_place2 varchar
        ) AS
$func$
    SELECT 
        g.gid,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM g.created)::int,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM g.finished)::int,
        g.letters,
        g.values,
        g.bid,
        m.tiles,
        m.score,
        /* HOW TO OPTIMIZE THE FOLLOWING CASE STATEMENTS? */
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.player1 ELSE g.player2 END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.player2 ELSE g.player1 END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.score1 ELSE g.score2 END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.score2 ELSE g.score1 END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN s1.female ELSE s2.female END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN s2.female ELSE s1.female END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN s1.given ELSE s2.given END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN s2.given ELSE s1.given END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN s1.photo ELSE s2.photo END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN s2.photo ELSE s1.photo END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN s1.place ELSE s2.place END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN s2.place ELSE s1.place END,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.played1 ELSE g.played2 END)::int,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.played2 ELSE g.played1 END)::int,
        ARRAY_TO_STRING(CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.hand1 ELSE g.hand2 END, ''),
        REGEXP_REPLACE(ARRAY_TO_STRING(CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.hand2 ELSE g.hand1 END, ''), '.', '?', 'g'),
    FROM words_games g 
        LEFT JOIN words_moves m ON m.gid = g.gid
        -- find move record with the most recent timestamp
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM words_moves m2 
            WHERE m2.gid = m.gid
            AND m2.played > m.played)
    LEFT JOIN words_social s1 ON s1.uid = g.player1
        -- find social record with the most recent timestamp
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM words_social s 
            WHERE s1.uid = s.uid
            AND s.stamp > s1.stamp)
    LEFT JOIN words_social s2 ON s2.uid = g.player2
        -- find social record with the most recent timestamp
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM words_social s 
            WHERE s2.uid = s.uid
            AND s.stamp > s2.stamp)
    WHERE in_uid IN (g.player1, g.player2)
    AND (g.finished IS NULL OR g.finished > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day');

$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

As you can see in the custom SQL function above, in the effort to always return the user data as `player1`, `given1`, `score1` I use numerous CASE statements (so that fetched columns can be swapped when needed):

```
    CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.score1 ELSE g.score2 END,
```

My question is: if it is possible to optimize the above SELECT query (without switching to slower PL/pgSQL)?

**UPDATE:**

Geoff at [the mailing list](http://postgresql.nabble.com/How-to-optimize-SELECT-query-with-multiple-CASE-statements-td5928371.html) has provided a nice suggestion to use CASE already when JOINing:

```
SELECT 
        g.gid,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM g.created)::int,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM g.finished)::int,
        g.letters,
        g.values,
        g.bid,
        m.tiles,
        m.score,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.player1 ELSE g.player2 END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.player2 ELSE g.player1 END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.score1 ELSE g.score2 END,
        CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.score2 ELSE g.score1 END,
        s1.female,
        s2.female,
        s1.given,
        s2.given,
        s1.photo,
        s2.photo,
        s1.place,
        s2.place,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.played1 ELSE g.played2 END)::int,
        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.played2 ELSE g.played1 END)::int,
        ARRAY_TO_STRING(CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.hand1 ELSE g.hand2 END, ''),
        REGEXP_REPLACE(ARRAY_TO_STRING(CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.hand2 ELSE g.hand1 END, ''), '.', '?', 'g')
FROM words_games g 
LEFT JOIN words_moves m ON m.gid = g.gid
        -- find move record with the most recent timestamp
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM words_moves m2 
                WHERE m2.gid = m.gid
                AND m2.played > m.played)
LEFT JOIN words_social s1 ON s1.uid = in_uid
        -- find social record with the most recent timestamp
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM words_social s 
                WHERE s1.uid = s.uid
                AND s.stamp > s1.stamp)
LEFT JOIN words_social s2 ON s2.uid = (CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN g.player2 ELSE g.player1 END)
        -- find social record with the most recent timestamp
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM words_social s 
                WHERE s2.uid = s.uid
                AND s.stamp > s2.stamp)
WHERE in_uid IN (g.player1, g.player2)
AND (g.finished IS NULL OR g.finished > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1 day');
```

Comment: How do you *know* that it is suboptimal? It are only two sets of values that may (or may not) need to be swapped in the outer query, *after* the query already has retrieved the needed data (one for the game, plus two for the players)

Comment: Yes, I am not sure. And actually I'd like to optimize 2 things: performance and readability.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the case expressions,  since they are in the select list.

Comment: I agree that is ugly ;-] Another way would be to keep the {player1,player2} notation, or adapt something like in boardgames {player_black, player_white} or ballgames {team_home, team_visitors} and/or leave the swapping to the presentation layer.

Comment: Does it make sense to add column: `g.player1 <> in_uid AS should_swap,` and then use it in the CASE statements?

Comment: Why is the column order important?

Comment: I can't correlate your query with the screenshot so I don't really understand what your ideal query should be. Thus I have as simple question:  do you systematically need all the columns? Or do you need only the columns related to a single player (which can be in the matches table either player 1 or player2) ??

Comment: When a player connects (via Websockets) to the game server, I send her all her active games and I swap the fields, so this player is always player1, score1, given1 (and never player2, score2, given2). That is why I have all the CASE statements in the above SELECT query.

Comment: PL/pgSQL is not slower although I avoid procedural whenever possible which is almost always. But in this case I think it would be simpler than my posted answer.

Comment: To avoid multiple cases you can use [Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/rowtypes.html): `CASE WHEN g.player1 = in_uid THEN (g.player1, g.score1,...)::tp_game_data ELSE (g.player2, g.score2,...)::tp_game_data END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lateral` and `distinct on` (IMO) contribute for readability. `distinct on` will also have an impact on performance although I can't guess if positive or negative.

```
select
    g.gid,
    extract(epoch from g.created)::int created,
    extract(epoch from g.finished)::int finished,
    g.letters,
    g.values,
    g.bid,
    m.tiles,
    m.score,
    r.*
from
    words_games g
    left join (
        select distinct on (gid, played) *
        from words_moves
        order by gid, played desc
    ) words_moves m on m.gid = g.gid
    left join (
        select distinct on (uid, stamp) *
        from words_social
        order by uid, stamp desc
    ) words_social s1 on s1.uid = g.player1
    left join (
        select distinct on (uid, stamp) *
        from words_social
        order by uid, stamp desc
    ) words_social s2 on s2.uid = g.player2
    cross join lateral (
        select
            g.player1, g.player2,
            extract(epoch from g.player1)::int, extract(epoch from g.player2)::int,
            array_to_string(g.hand1, ''),
            regexp_replace(array_to_string(g.hand2, ''), '.', '?', 'g'),
            g.score1, g.score2,
            s1.female, s2.female,
            s1.given, s2.given,
            s1.photo, s2.photo,
            s1.place, s2.place
        where g.player1 = in_uid
        union all
        select
            g.player2, g.player1,
            extract(epoch from g.player2)::int, extract(epoch from g.player1)::int,
            array_to_string(g.hand2, ''),
            regexp_replace(array_to_string(g.hand1, ''), '.', '?', 'g'),
            g.score2, g.score1,
            s2.female, s1.female,
            s2.given, s1.given,
            s2.photo, s1.photo,
            s2.place, s1.place
        where g.player1 != in_uid
    ) r
where
    in_uid in (g.player1, g.player2)
    and (g.finished is null or g.finished > current_timestamp - interval '1 day')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're worried about the many case statements and it is always the same conditions, you can pull this condition out and have *two* selects, e.g.

```
select ...
       g.player1, g.player2,
       extract(epoch from g.played1)::int, extract(epoch from g.played2)::int,
       ...
       g.score1, g.score2,
       ...
```

and the other (identical) select with the columns swapped

```
select ...
       g.player2, g.player1,
       extract(epoch from g.played2)::int, extract(epoch from g.played1)::int,
       ...
       g.score2, g.score1,
       ...
```

Although, as @joop and @jarlh already questioned, first test, if this is really a performance problem at all.

Comment: Note: in a previous post, the OP had a similar (rather bulky) solution, using a UNION http://stackoverflow.com/q/40304011/2235885

Comment: Yes, I had UNION SELECT with swapped fields before :-) but I am trying to optimize this statement, since it is the most frequently called one.

Comment: Then maybe looking at `explain (analyze)`  for both queries `select union` and `select case` gives more insight.